# What part of android is responsible for alerts?

Tags: notifications, calendar, alarm, alerts

Some time ago I customized my Android phone by removing all the bloatware and by setting the permissions for a lot of system apps with lbe security center to a more privacy-friendly state. This included disabling access to my phone number, IMEI, SIM number, Internet access for apps that shouldn't have it, and other things. I only removed which I considered bloatware, such as several Samsung apps, Google junk I didn't need such as search, widget, sync adapters,... And I customized the permissions of for example Google services framework (no SIM number access, and other set to on demand), Android market (no phone number and location), maps (location on demand, no phone number/IMEI)...

After that I ran into a problem, namely my calendar alerts don't function properly  and I noticed that my alarms don't activate the second time (using galaxy s3 app). The calendar alerts sometimes function correctly but sometimes either not on time or not at all, and I found on the Internet that some people are experiencing the same problems with the calendar and exactly the same way as for when the alerts do work and when they don't. Some apps that seem to rely on the Android system for alerts (such as wordfeud, buienalarm), don't work correctly either. I noticed, but cannot say this for certain, that the alerts do work once or several times after I enable WiFi for the first time (or was it mobile Internet?)

I have to mention that apps that have  their own alert/notification system do work correctly, such as chaton (using Samsung push app), whatsapp and Trillian.

Now I'd like to know if anyone can tell me which app or feature is responsible for these alerts and notifications and/or how to fix this properly. I installed a custom version of the Galaxy S3 Android 4.1.2 ROM of wanamlite using the mobile Odin app but my problems aren't solved.

specs :

Android 4.1.2 wanamlite
Galaxy S3 international I9300

Comment: K-mail is also one of the apps that function correctly

Answer (score 1):

You should revert the permissions of the Google Services Framework app. This is the app that controls the connection to the Google Servers, and without it Sync and other things will not work.

You should also revert the permissions for all adapters, and non-bloatware system apps. There is a reason the apps need this data.

Comment: Alarms are (or at least should be) something completely local. Imagine you're cut off from all network (sitting in a bunker for a week, to give an extreme example). Alarms should still work -- and they could not work when they need to be triggered externally. So I doubt your suggestion will improve the situation much.

Comment: I agree with Izzy, I re-enabled the permissions for the services framework app before and it didn't fix it. I did notice that cutting it off from the Internet makes the Google play app nonfunctional after a while because it can't connect to the Google account.while I noticed that the framework periodically connects to the Internet to keep the account logged in or so

Comment: And out of my own experience, I haven't removed any important apps. Removing Google apps doesn't necessarily mean it will break compatibility. I just removed features I didn't need and that in one way or another posed a privacy issue

Comment: To add to my first comment: I have one device I kept offline for days (up to a week or more). Alerts still worked perfectly. Of course, new calendar events added from another device wouldn't turn up on the offline-device ;)

Answer (score 1):

Some devices do have problems with at least the calendar alerts. Or at least partial ones: What does a single chime help if I'm just "out of reach", as the device is on my desk while I'm being for the "private place". Alarms thus should repeat until explicitly dismissed, at least for a given time frame (30min minimum).

To work around this problem, the playstore offers several apps like e.g. [Calendar Event Reminder (CER)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.foobarsoft.calendareventreminder) or [CalendarAlarmHelper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.DailyTimer.CalendarAlarmHelperFree), which might be worth a look for you. I'm using the former, and it never missed to alert me. [HandyPhone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ua.sydorov.handyphone) might also be worth a look in this context (at least if you're running ICS or above).

<sup>side-note: Yeah, I'm also using LBE in a similar manner as you do, so it works even then ;)</sup>

Comment: But how come that's the case when everything functioned correctly in the beginning, even after rooting my device. But then one day, after the cleanup, I noticed that I wasn't getting calendar notifications. And recently I noticed that the alarm app doesn't do the second alarm anymore, just the first soft alarm works.

Comment: As I wrote above: Some devices have this problem *generally*. In your case, it might be something more specific: I guess something's silently "crashing" in the background while trying to "make a call home" before triggering the alert notification. You might need to investigate with `logcat` (e.g. setting an alert to fire in 2 minutes, and then watch logcat until the alert should trigger; this way you should be able to catch the error behind it).